# SpriteKit SKTextureAtlas atlasWithDictionary method

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, xcode6

I'm not sure if I'm doing this wrong or if there's something broken with the "[atlasWithDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTextureAtlas/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKTextureAtlas/atlasWithDictionary:)" method.

This is how I used it:

```
NSArray* imageNames = @[ @"image1", @"image2", @"image3", @"image4"];
NSMutableDictionary* tempDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.count; i++) {
    UIImage* texture = [UIImage imageNamed:imageNames[i]];

    [tempDict setObject:texture forKey:imageNames[i]];
}



SKTextureAtlas* atlasFullOfTextures = [SKTextureAtlas atlasWithDictionary:tempDict];
```

and then later in my code, whenever I would do

```
SKTexture* tex = [atlasFullOfTextures textureNamed:@"image1"];
```

I just get a nil object. I did a bit of troubleshooting and found that

```
NSArray* arrayOfNames = [atlasFullOfTextures textureNames];
```

returns an empty array.

Also, I know that the images are loading fine as I temporarily made the dictionary public and successfully made SKTextures from the UIImage objects.

Does anyone have any idea what's happening?

Comment: I implemented your code and it works as expected. Did you add the image files to your project? Why are you using atlasWithDictionary instead of creating an atlas folder?

Comment: Yes I added the files. I even tested by individually making textures from them. And the reason I'm doing it this way is I'm trying to bring in some vector art to reduce the filesize, but without texture atlases, draw calls can easily skyrocket. So I have to render the vector into bitmaps in memory, then form an atlas at runtime.

Comment: Well eff me... I just tried it again by simply uncommenting code that I had written whilst trying earlier and it worked. I really hope it was something I made an error with and not that it's inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTextureAtlas/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKTextureAtlas/atlasWithDictionary:):

> The keys in the dictionary represent the names of the individual
>   textures. The associated object for each key can be:
>
> - An NSString object that contains a file system path to a file that    contains the texture
> - An NSURL object that contains a file system path to a file that    contains the texture
> - A UIImage object
> - An NSImage object

You are not providing a path/url to the image, you just use image names with no way of telling where they might be. You will probably also have to specify the file extension as Sprite Kit probably won't try to guess it. If these are textures obtained or created at runtime, they will not be in the bundle so you have to specify what the path to each texture is as well (usually in the appdata or documents folder).

If these images *are* in the bundle, you probably have to specify the bundle directory. But there's little reason not to have the atlas be created by Xcode at compile time in this case and then using `atlasNamed:`.

Comment: The strings are filenames that would be read in as a UIImage, but I am also adding procedurally generated renders to the atlas. For some reason, it randomly started to work by accident, but thanks anyways! :)

Comment: Oh, I overlooked the UIImage line. But why create an atlas at runtime from images already in the bundle? After all if you do this on compile time your app will load faster.

Comment: I wanted to reduce the draw count to include prerendered files as well as procedural renders in the same draw, as well as being able to have more control over the compression of png files than what Apple allows through atlas creation (I can shave off an additional 50%+ file size through https://compressor.io/ or similar in most cases).